# API for defining parametric probability distributions

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Mathematica has a lot of machinery for working with predefined probability distributions. It is not clear how to make that machinery work with a new distribution.

Suppose I want to define a brand new distribution

```
MyDistribution[a, b, c]
```

What is the minimum I need to specify for all the other machinery to kick in?

Do I just need to specify a PDF or CDF? How do I associate it with `MyDistribution`?

`ProbabilityDistribution` does some of what I want, but has limitations.
Suppose I define

```
  MyDistribution[a_, b_, c_] := ProbabilityDistribution[SomeFun[a,b,c,x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

then `MyDistribution[a, b, c]` will automatically be rewritten to `ProbabilityDistribution[SomeFun[a,b,c,x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]`,
losing information about what the parameters of the distribution are. This makes it hard to have general purpose Fisher information function that works with user defined distributions.

---

Here is an example of the information loss I am thinking of.
Mathematica has a `FisherInformation` function that uses the explicit distribution parameters to structure the resulting matrix

```
AppendTo[$ContextPath, "Statistics`Library`"]
FisherInformation[NormalDistribution[m, s]] // MatrixForm
```

The row and columns of the resulting matrix correspond to the explicit parameters.
It is unclear this function should be extended to work on distributions defined using `ProbabilityDistribution`

Comment: What information about the parameters is being lost?  If you type `?MyDistribution`, you'll get the complete definition.  What are the limitations of `ProbabilityDistribution` you mention?  (I'm not suggesting that there aren't any but rather that it is not obvious what limitations affect what you want to do.)

Comment: For one thing it loses the canonical order of the parameters. `ProbabilityDistribution[1/(E^((m - x)^2/(2*s^2))*(Sqrt[2*Pi]*s)), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]` does not tell you the order of `m` and `s`, whereas `NormalDistribution[m,s]` does. Also `SomeFun` may additionally refer to `d`, `e`, `f` which are just undefined constants and not actual parameters of the family. After the rewriting this distinction is lost.

Comment: It would really help if you could give a specific example.

Comment: Well, you are using an undocumented function; with these things, consider yourself lucky if it works, but don't expect too much of them.

Comment: You should check out the "Create your own distribution" presentation by @Sasha Pavlyk. It is getting a bit old but much of it is still probably relevant http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2011/mathematics-and-statistics.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to argue that parameter information and paradise are not lost (until there's a specific counter-example).

```
(* Define some function *)
someFun[x_, μ_, σ_, a_, b_, c_] := (a/σ) Exp[-(x - μ)^b/(c σ^2)]

(* Define a probability density function that depends on someFun and
   some yet to be given constants *)
myDistribution[μ_, σ_] := ProbabilityDistribution[someFun[z, μ, σ, a, b, c], 
   {z, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> σ > 0]
```

Now show the definitions of the functions:

```
?someFun
?myDistribution
```

[image: Function definitions]

Now work with the probability distribution:

```
(* Set the constants so that myDistribution represents a legitimate 
probability distribution *)
constants = {a -> 1/Sqrt[2 π], b -> 2, c -> 2};

(* Determine some properties of myDistribution *)
Mean[myDistribution[3, 4] /. constants]
(* 3 *)

Variance[myDistribution[3, sigma] /. constants]
(* sigma^2 *)

Expectation[(r - mean)^3, r \[Distributed] myDistribution[mean, sigma] /. constants]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: For those too lazy to derive normalization constants: set `Method -> "Normalize"` in `ProbabilityDistribution[]`.

Comment: I have added an example to my question

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer ... more like an extended comment that is too long for the comment box. But I found the question interesting, for a number of reasons:

1. I did not know that Mma had a `FisherInformation` function hidden away where you found it - how DID you find it?
2. Your question actually highlights one of my pet dislikes - which is the naming of distributions as black boxes - which is exactly what you are trying to emulate. Even for something as well known as the Normal distribution, there are competing parameterisations. For other distributions, there is not even agreement on what functional form the distribution should take, or any number of competing common forms that co-exist. Even when there is such agreement as to functional form, your own example shows beautifully why using black box names is often just inappropriate. You enter:

$\rightarrow$

```
   FisherInformation[NormalDistribution[m, s]] // MatrixForm
```

There is no such thing as the Fisher Information of a Normal distribution.  Fisher Information is carried out wrt parameters, not with respect to black boxes. Are the parameters of $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$:

- $\mu$ and $\sigma$, or
- $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$?

Well, it can be either. And we may want to consider both cases, or something entirely different. Each approach is a different problem, with a different solution.

Consider your example of a Normal random variable with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/mrnormalagainhello.png))</sub>

The Fisher Information on $(\mu, \sigma)$ is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/fisherinfmusig.png))</sub>

The Fisher Information on $(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/fisherinfmusig2.png))</sub>

To avoid any confusion, I should note that I am using here the `FisherInformation` function in the *mathStatica* add-on to *Mathematica*, and as declaration, that I am one of the authors.

Comment: I found `FisherInformation` because somebody pointed me to another function in `Statistics\`Library` and since I could not find any documentation I just did `??` on the whole library.

Comment: I agree that the way Mathematica does distributions is problematic, but I am trying to work with what I got.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(*  "10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"  *)

dist[m_, s_] = 
  ProbabilityDistribution[
   1/(E^((m - x)^2/(2*s^2))*(Sqrt[2*Pi]*s)), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {s > 0, Element[m, Reals]}];

AppendTo[$ContextPath, "Statistics`Library`"];

(fi1 = FisherInformation[NormalDistribution[m, s]]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
(fi2 = FisherInformation[dist[m, s]]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Although `fi2` is much slower

```
fi1 === fi2

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Using your example I think I finally see the OP's concern.  If `dist` has the parameters defined in the reverse order, then one obtains the exact same matrix (even though the rows and columns should have been reversed) if the `FisherInformation` function used the parameters in the same order as the function definition.  But it appears that `FisherInformation` uses a lexicographic order:  `FisherInformation[dist[m,s]]` gives a differently ordered matrix than `FisherInformation[dist[z,s]]`.  At least that's my current theory subject to change by facts.